# rhapsody API: how to get mutliple selected elements

Tags: rhapsody

Ho can I get multiple selected elements with the Java-API?

The Application-Interface (`RPIApplication`) seems to have only a `getSelectedElement()` method. Is there a way to get multiple items?

I saw the get `getSelectedGraphElements()` method, but it seems that this one only gives diagram elements.

But I want Model-Elements and also the possibility to get selected items from the tree view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, I think there is a method called getListOfSelectedElements(), which returns an IRPCollection.

Regards, Simon

Comment: thanks - indeed. that a great and consistent API design -_-